# Can you bind a DataTrigger to an Attached Property?

Tags: wpf, binding, datatrigger

In WPF, is it possible for a DataTrigger to bind to an attached property?

I essentially want to use a converter on an attached property to provide a style when a particular validation rule has been broken. I am using markup like the following:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Validation.Errors, 
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                       Converter={StaticResource RequiredToBoolConverter}}" 
                       Value="True">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
</DataTrigger>
```

However, when this runs, I get the following:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 39 :
>   BindingExpression path error:
>   'Validation' property not found on
>   'object' ''TextBox' (Name='')'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=Validation.Errors;
>   DataItem='TextBox' (Name=''); target
>   element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

If I change my DataTrigger binding path to "Text", I do not get the databinding error (but of course it does not provide the behaviour I am seeking).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to wrap the property in parentheses:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors).YourAttachedProperty,...
```

Comment: This is documented on MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752300.aspx#Path_Syntax

Comment: New link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms752300%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Path_Syntax